# MicroSD card cannot be permanently written on

Tags: sd-card, gparted, micro-sd-card

I have a microSD card that seems to work fine while plugged in. I can e.g. create a file and it will stay while plugged in, but whenever I eject the card and plug it back in, the file is gone.

Formatting it with `gparted` seems to work at first (and takes a reasonably long time) but after some time the old partitions reappear (and always upon replugging).

A Benchmark using `gnome-disks` returns read and write rates of both about 20MB/s.

Plugging it into a Raspberry Pi, I can boot from the card and seem to be able to write files on it, but again they are gone on reboot.

So it's **not** in read-only mode but somehow still I cannot permanently write to it, although no application has returned an error yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using card correctly (sync/umount etc. before ejecting it), then
it is probable that the card itself is fake/defective (especially likely if you bought it off ebay or such). You can check with [F3 utility](http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/), for example.